# Programs to use for 'graphical replay' of data taken from a remote data logger

Tags: data-visualization

Ok, so I'm new and not really familiar with the rules, so sorry if the question isn't written in the right way.  I asked the below question on Stack Overflow and got told I would be better off asking for program suggestions on here, so here goes...

I've been working on automating some tasks that we have to do at work using data recorded on remote data logging equipment.  The remote data loggers are connected to railway signal equipment and record the position of relays (either UP or DOWN).  These relays are used to operate lineside signalling equipment, so knowing at what time they were in a particular position enables us to tell what was happening on the railway at that time.  The loggers write a simple text file, with each line in the file giving a date and time, the name of the relay and what position it changed to (e.g. UP to DOWN or DOWN to UP).

So far, I've written a vba code for a macro to run in MS Excel in order to automatically dial up a remote logger (yes, we still use dialup), log in, get the user requested hours-worth of data, save text file to a new excel spreadsheet and then annotate the download with notes at the end of each line, helping our guys understand what the equipment was doing during that hour.

The next step I'd like to do is to create a separate application that our guys can use in order to then 'play back' the data, in real time or 'fast forward' mode, as a visual representation of the railway. The idea is they can see a map of the railway that the logger monitors (rather like the screens that the signaller's have upstairs) and be able to see what was going on - i.e. trains moving along, signals changing colour, points moving etc.  This functionality would help immensely in allowing us to be able to identify equipment faults quicker, meaning less delay to trains.

I've had a go at writing some vba code in Excel to try and achieve the graphical replay functionality but I think it is very cumbersome and is never going to be suitable.  The code I made ran a simple clock that updated once a second and then the code ran through the lines of data logger data, looking to see if any lines had a similar time stamp, if they did have a similar time stamp then the code ran a MASSIVE 'IF' statement, looking to see which relay it was that had changed state, then whether the relay was UP or DOWN and finally updating the shapes on the little map of the railway line that I had drawn, changing their colour or making them disappear, in order to graphically represent the event logged by the data logger.  There were several problems with this method.  Firstly the code was massively complicated and poor old Excel had a hard time processing it all - it had to be split up into chunks to make it run which made interpreting the replay difficult, sort of obscruing the entire point of creating the code in the first place.  There can be up to 394 relays all monitored by a single data logger, so that MASSIVE if statement really was quite big.  Plus, excel had a habit of either crashing (saying "stack overflow", ironically) or occasionally not updating the shapes until the macro had finished executing, making the whole exercise pretty pointless.

So, now you know most of my life story, here is the question:

Do you clever people know of a better way to achieve the graphical replay functionality that I'm after?  Is there a simpler or better way of doing it, using another program or application other than Excel and VBA code?

I wanted to attach a screenshot of a little sample of the data logger data that we have to work with but apparently I need 10 reputation to do that.  I haven't added the vba code for the graphical replay that I developed because it is massive and I can't see any way that it could ever be made to work much better, given the limitations of using VBA and Excel.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and extra super duper thanks if you have any suggestions of a better program or application to use,

Matt

Comment: I think you could write a more efficient code using [Python](https://www.python.org/). It is fairly intuitive and has good graphing capabilities. See [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) for example

Comment: OK thanks Timmy.  That looks pretty interesting.  I'll give it a whirl and see where it takes me!

Comment: " I asked the below question on Stack Overflow and got told I would be better off asking for program suggestions on here" - you were misled. Ask for program suggestions on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ Ask here for an existing application to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar using [Python](http://python.org) and [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org) several times.

Points to consider:

- Python is easier to learn than VBA
- Much more long term support and stability
- Free
- Cross platform
- Rather than a massive if statement use a dictionary of ID & State V Position and Bitmap
- You can access your current excel with xlrd but better to use the text file format, (you can even access your files inside of .zip files).
- Add the serial library and doing a scheduled dial-up, login, download would be less than 20 lines of code.
- You could even have a web interface.
- Lots of help on SO and other sites

Comment: Ah thank you very much Steve. I haven't started using it just yet but when I start I'll bear everything you said in mind.

Comment: +1 for Python. See my question softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16246/gratis-python-ide-for-commercial-use  For the map, you might consider Google Maps, which are very easy to use, although you need a licence for heavy usage, or Open Street Map. Sounds like a fun project. I wish that I could do it ("do you have budget for outsourcing?", he asked cheekily)